# Shouldn't Promise.all work as the function passed to .then?

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

This code works in Chrome(47), FF(43) and Node.js(4.2.2) :

```
Promise.resolve()
.then(function() {
    return new Array(5).fill(Promise.resolve('hello world'));
})
.then(function(promisesArr) {
    return Promise.all(promisesArr);
})
.then(function(allResults) {
    console.log(allResults);
}).catch(function(err) {
    console.log('FAILED: ' + err);
});
```

The second .then however contains a 'useless' anonymous function (calls a single function with the same arguments, returning the result).

As far as I understand, this pattern can and should be replaced by referencing the function itself directly, like so :

```
Promise.resolve()
.then(function() {
    return new Array(5).fill(Promise.resolve('hello world'));
})
.then(Promise.all)
.then(function(allResults) {
    console.log(allResults);
}).catch(function(err) {
    console.log('FAILED: ' + err);
});
```

However, while this works in FF, it fails in Chrome and (predictably since it is also based on V8) on Node, respectively with:

> FAILED: TypeError: undefined is not a function

and

> FAILED: TypeError: _runMicrotasks is not a function

Am I correct in thinking that this is a bug ? Or is my understanding that the anonymous function can be replaced with a simple reference to the function to be called incorrect ?

Comment: Maybe you'll need to bind the function to the `Promise` global. `Promise.all.bind(Promise)`

Comment: The only issue I can think of is that you're not returning the promise, so you need that callback. returns are only implied on singel expression arrow functions, iirc.

Comment: @MinusFour hole in one ! Can't believe I didn't see that :) Now it makes me wonder how my code even works in FF. Add your comment as an answer and I'll accept it !

Comment: Avoid bind. Use arrow functions instead: `.then(promises => Promise.all(promises))`.

Comment: @SterlingArcher there's no need for an implied return; in the second version, I'm giving a reference to Promise.all as the function to be called, not calling Promise.all() myself and returning its results.

Comment: @jib I love arrow function but in this case the whole point is to avoid an unnecessary anonymous function, which arrow function still introduces. On top of that, I can't use them yet in this specific app since iOS is a target and Safari 9.2 for iOS does not yet support them :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would largely depend on how the function is defined. If the function uses the object's context then you'll need to provide one that fits that specific context (i.e. the Promise object).

If the function uses `this` then you'll need to do:

```
Promise.all.bind(Promise);
```

But if the function uses the `Promise` object directly then it doesn't matter. I'd still bind it though, for compatibility with other `Promise` implementations.